# How to get wider text for Checkbox widget?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How can I configure the `ipywidgets` Checkbox for long text strings as in,

```
 c = Checkbox(description=' this is some very long very long text',value=False)
```

and not get the text to be squeezed and wrapped in the encompassing Jupyter notebook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this is the cell with the checkbox

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
HTML('<style> .widget-hbox .widget-label { max-width:350ex; text-align:left} </style>')
```

and it'll change the widths and alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

c = widgets.Checkbox(
    description='This is some very long very long text',
    value=False,
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='100%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to bundle it with `Label`:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout
from IPython.display import display

checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, disabled=False, layout=Layout(width='30px'))
label = widgets.Label('description', layout=Layout(width='500px', margin='6px 0 0 -10px'))
box = widgets.HBox([checkbox, label])
display(box)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set the width to the left of the checkbox and also set the overall width independently

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

c = widgets.Checkbox(
    description=' this is some very long very long text',
    value=False)
c.style = {'description_width': '0px'}  # sets the width to the left of the check box
c.layout.width = 'auto' # sets the overall width check box widget
c
```